# Update list with RSS data

Tags: android, rss, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am working on displaying some RSS data in a ListView. I was reading up on the onProgressUpdate() method provided by the Asynchronous task class.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use this method to update the listview as each item from XML is retrieved?

I overrided the method here:

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

I am getting this error:

**Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

EDIT: I just read an article saying this error is generated from trying to update the UI thread from within the background thread inside of the `doInBackground()` method. In my case I am calling the `onProgressUpdate()` in the `doInBackground()` method. I was trying to add the effect of the list populating as each item was downloaded.

Any suggestions of how I could achieve this would be great!

Log cat:

```
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:318)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1819)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:813)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:5958)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at com.example.simplerss.MainActivity$PostTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:148)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at com.example.simplerss.MainActivity$PostTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:123)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at com.example.simplerss.MainActivity$PostTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-13 00:41:09.195: E/AndroidRuntime(32239):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Add the full StackTrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my case I am calling the onProgressUpdate() in the doInBackground()
>   method.

You have to call `publishProgress()` instead. If you directly call `onProgressUpdate()`, that is still running from the background thread and so, will fail.

You should take a look at the AsyncTask [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), they provide an example.